# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous while checking the boolean column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe contain one column with boolean values i.e 0 or 1.
I am trying to check if its 0, then increment the counter for `count_0` else increment for `count_1`.

```
if(df1['Project_is_approved']==0):
    count_0 = count_0 + 1;
if(df1['Project_is_approved']==1):
    count_1 = count_1 + 1;
```

Either `count_0` or `count_1` should increment.
Instead i am getting error at,

```
if(df1['Project_is_approved']==0):
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tell pandas to check if a series (column) is equal to something, there are a number of things it could interpret it as. By design, pandas chooses not to guess, and instead throws an error, which should lead you into using more specific methods.

I'm inferring that your endgame is to count how many 0s and how many 1s are contained in the series. For that, assuming the columns "Project_is_approved" consists of 0s and 1s, you can simply do the following:

```py
df1["Project_is_approved"][df1["Project_is_approved"] == 1].count()
```

The way this works is, from left to right:
1. Select the "Project_is_approved" column of `df1`.
2. From that, apply a boolean mask: only keep elements for which the content of "Project_is_approved" is equal to 1.
3. Count how many elements are in this selection.

You can do the same to count 0s by just replacing the 1 with a 0 inside the mask.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this, is to sum up the column:

```
count_1 = sum(df1['Project_is_approved'])
count_0 = len(df1['Project_is_approved']) - count_1
```

This works for both, proper boolean values `True` and `False` and integer values: `0` and `1`